# tasks Scheduler and CPU isolation in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

I'm a kernel noob including schedulers. I understand that there is a IO scheduler and a task scheduler and according to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199265/relationship-between-io-scheduler-and-cpu-process-scheduler) IO scheduler uses normal tasks that are handled by the task schedule in the end.

> 1. So if I run an user space thread that was assigned to an isolated core (using isolcpus) and it will do some IO operation, will the the
>      task created by the IO scheduler get executed on the isolated core ?
> 2. Since CFS seems to favor user interaction does this mean that CPU intensive threads might get a lower CPU time in the long run?
>      Isolating cores can help mitigate this issue?
> 3. Isolating cores can decrease the scheduling latency (the time it takes for a thread that was marked as runnable to get executed ) for 
>      the threads that are pined to the isolated cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I run an user space thread that was assigned to an isolated core
>   (using isolcpus) and it will do some IO operation, will the the task
>   created by the IO scheduler get executed on the isolated core ?

What `isolcpus` is doing is taking that particular core out of kernel list of cpu where it can schedule tasks. So once you isolate a cpu from kernel's list of cpus it will never schedule any task on that core, no matter whether that core is idle or is being used by some other process/thread.

> Since CFS seems to favor user interaction does this mean that CPU
>   intensive threads might get a lower CPU time in the long run?
>   Isolating cores can help mitigate this issue?

Isolating cpu has a different use altogether in my opinion. Basically if your applications has both fast threads(threads with no system calls, and are latency sensitive) and slow threads(threads with system calls) you would want to have dedicated cpu cores for your fast threads so that they are not interrupted by kernel's scheduling process and hence can run to their completion without any noise. Fast threads are usually latency sensitive. On the other hand slow threads or threads which are not really latency sensitive and are doing supporting logic for your application need not have dedicated cpu cores. As mentioned earlier isloting cpu servers a different purpose. We do all this all the time in our organization.

> Isolating cores can decrease the scheduling latency (the time it takes
>   for a thread that was marked as runnable to get executed ) for the
>   threads that are pined to the isolated cores?

Since you are taking cpus from kernel's list of cpus this will surely impact other threads and processes, but then again you would want to pay extra thought and attention to what really is your latency sensitive code and you would want to separate it from your non-latency sensitive code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what would be the difference between "fast threads" and "cpu intensive threads" ? by cpu intensive threads I mean threads that run a lenghty calculation without doing system calls (for example image processing). To me they seem to be the same thing in which case I don't understand your remark that "Isolating cpu has a different use altogether in my opinion."

Comment: You are right that cpu intensive threads and fast threads are same in most of the cases.What i mean by that remark is that typically if you want your cpu intensive tasks to not being interrupted by scheduler then those are the ones that should be running on isolated cpus.Obviously if you isolate a cpu, lets you had 8 core machines and you isolated 2 of them then the scheduler would any further threads on these core, they effectively are not available for scheduler.

Comment: since you mentioned that you did this before, can you give me some hints about how you handle syncronisation between the threads that run on the isolated cores (and also between the threads the run on the isolated cores and threads running on other cores) ? Do you use OS provided sync primitives (mutexes, semaphores etc) or you came up with some custom sync mechanisms?

Comment: Well this question is little different from your original question, synchronizing application threads is a primitive problem and is typically handled very differently depending upon the language in which the application has been written.Since I am a python developer I can only tell about how you handle threads in python where we use Locks mainly.But as a side note isolating the thread would not impact thread synchronization because the application/thread data are stored in memory and cpu core is just running the thread, thread would still access variables/data from memory only.